# Stuck in d3..please help

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord, shifting

My 2006 Honda Accord is stuck in d3. It's just now happened. It still seems to be shifting like it would normally. And I can move the shifter down but it will not go from d3 to d, N, R, P......any help would be appreciated. I am praying it isn't the transmission..

Comment: This may sound silly, but did you push the shifter lock release button?

Comment: This seems like a shifter issue, not a transmission issue.